# How to disable window resize on clicking title bar?

Tags: gnome

very often ( several times a day [ but not always ]) on partially occluded windows where only a portion of its top left is visible when I single mouse click on top title bar that window will somehow auto resize itself

Anyone know how to disable this behavior ?

I could be wrong however I do not see this happen when more of a given window is visible

stock  Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but for the record, check auto-maximize value:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize
```

if the value is true, set to false:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter auto-maximize false
```

Comment: when I issue the `get` it shows true yet when I then issue the `set` to false then view results by again doing a `get` it still shows true ... ditto running the `set` as root

Comment: i ran it as my normal user and it worked. I beleive this is at user level preferences.

Comment: there are also those 2 settings to change when touching screen edges: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436114/disable-auto-resizing-of-windows-when-dragged-to-the-top-and-or-screen-edges